# Why cant i access my static variable inside another class

Tags: java, static, return, getter

HI all I'm pretty new to this and just got hold of the instance and static variables.What i want to do is declare something inside as a static variable use it inside that class , assign a value to it by a user input , and do a calculation using that input and send this input inside another class (which doesn't have the main method ) and use it inside an array. Is it possible ? if so how ? from the way i did it it says that the variable can not be identified so obviously im wrong.I know i can do this using setter and getter but i dont know how to do so .Thank you so much in advance.What i have so far

```
  public class Character {

       public static int amount =0;

       public void calculate(){

       amount=sc.nextInt();

       if(amount<0){
                 System.out.print("You are broke");
                       }
        else{
              System.out.print("You are ok You have"+amount);
            }
  }
```

Inside another class i want to use this amount

```
public class calculation2{

    int [] arr=new int[amount];

    public void smile(){

      bla bla bla bla

     }
}
```

How can i go about this , what am i dointwrong and any suggestions to fix it ? thank you so mumch

Comment: Public static variables are generally considered to be *terrible* design, because of the fact that you have absolutely no control over how they are used (or abused).  You should really re-think what you're trying to solve here.

Comment: you can access it by `Character.amount`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is static, you can refer to the static amount variable in calculation2 by doing this:

```
int [] arr=new int[Character.amount];

public void smile(){

  System.out.println(Character.amount);

 }
```

though you shouldn't code like that. Use static when something has an actual value or return value and you want to use that in another class.

Answer (score 0):

This is not right way of coding:
However in your code, you ave declared static variable as amount as public, so you can access it in smile method as:

```
int [] arr=new int[Character.amount];    
public void smile(){
      System.out.println(Character.amount);
     }
```